# Wrap nth-childs with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Hi I have a pattern of nth-child selectors for a grid I've build.
For more control I want that some of them are get wrapped into div.

I've tried to achieve this with jquery wrapAll. But this will break the pattern of the grid.

So my question is if I wrote something wrong or if there is another method to achieve this

This is what I have:

```js
$(".item:nth-child(6n+1), .item:nth-child(6n+2), .item:nth-child(6n+3)")
.wrapAll( "<div class='row'></div>");
$(".item:nth-child(6n+4), .item:nth-child(6n+5)")
.wrapAll( "<div class='row'></div>");
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  margin: 50px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.projectTitle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  top: 100%;
}

/* ROW */
.item:nth-child(6n+1) { width: 25%; }
.item:nth-child(6n+2) { width: 25%; }
.item:nth-child(6n+3) { width: 25%; }

/* ROW */
.item:nth-child(6n+4) { width: 80%; }
.item:nth-child(6n+5) { width: 40%; }
.item:nth-child(6n)   { width: 40%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/875x1200">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<br><span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<br><span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x650">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x450">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/875x625">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/655x480">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x650">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x450">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/520x250">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x625">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So how does it not work? ... I mean, as we don't know the _pattern_ it is difficult to answer

Comment: Change to `$(".item:nth-child(6n+1), .item:nth-child(6n+2), .item:nth-child(6n+3)")
.prepend( "<div >Group 1</div>");` will see why. Also note wrapping will change the children indexing also and therefore affect your `nth-child()` css rules

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for your answers. The expected result based on my css selector pattern should look like this: 
`<div class="row">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
</div>`
****Repeating*****

I want to achieve with jquery that the first three elements get wrapped into  a div with the class="row"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update comment it appears you want to have each group of 3 items in their own row.

Can use a loop that increments by 3 and [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get each item group and append a new row every iteration

```js
var $cont = $('.row').parent(),
  $items = $('.item:gt(2)');

for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i = i + 3) {
  $('<div class="row">').append($items.slice(i, i + 3)).appendTo($cont);
}
```

```css
.row {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Super nice! Thanks, this works.Would it also be possible to have two items in one div in the other 1 and in another 3 items?

Comment: Could increment the loop by 6 instead and make 3 slices and appends